# How to safely use "&" symbol in a javascript variable without it turning to "&amp;"?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
<button onclick="increment()">Increment</button>
<div id="iframe">
<script>
var id = 139000;
var link='<iframe src="https://somewebsite.com/something.aspx?sa=1&pid=' + id + '" height="600px" width="100%" />';
function increment(){
id++;
document.getElementById('iframe').innerHTML = id + link ;
}
</script>
</div>
```

But while executing, the `&` in `src=""` converts to `&amp;` which breaks the original URL and doesn't go to the desired destination. I looked up on the internet but as I am a noob, I was not able to figure it out. Please help me to make this work!

Comment: Shouldn't you change the `src` property of the iframe element?

Comment: Didn't get wdym? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I told you I am a noob, sry!

Comment: The above code is working in code pen. One suggestion though you can try using backtick instead of single quotes for defining the link variable.

Comment: It's `innerHTML` making the conversion. Create the iframe like this. `const iframe = document.createElement('iframe'); document.getElementById('iframe').append(iframe); iframe.src='https://somewebsite.com/something.aspx?sa=1&pid=' + id;`.

Comment: Can you write the whole code in a answer so I could tick your answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is

```
<button onclick="increment()">Increment</button>
<div id="iframe">
<script>
var id = 139000;
var link='<iframe src="https://somewebsite.com/something.aspx?sa=1&pid=' + id + 
'" height="600px" width="100%" />';
var new_link = link.replaceAll('&amp;','&');

function increment(){
id++;
document.getElementById('iframe').innerHTML = id + new_link;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Well, tried that already, it still changes the ```&```  to ```&amp;```. Is it because of the editor. I am trying to execute this on Blogger.

Comment: If you are looking for a free hosting, then try GitHub pages instead of Blogger because every platform has its own rules for the URL parsing

Comment: Okay! Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Although I tried this in my browser, even your code was working well, not changing & to &amp;

Comment: So it must be an issue from Blogger

Comment: This is like setting n = 1 and then wondering why n is not 7 ... Replacing non-existing characters does absolutely nothing here.

Comment: While we add dynamic urls when they get parsed the & in them get converted to &amp; automatically so that's why I have used this replaceAll thing

Comment: JS doesn't convert anything, it's `innerHTML`, there's nothing to replace in the string which was initialized a line above.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a blogger issue, and the reason behind happening is :

The character "&" is an ISO HTML reserved character used to denote the start of a parameter.

To overcome this the Blogger editor translate the `&` you enter to the HTML entity, `&amp;` ,  that will display `&` when the page or URL is rendered in a browser, so that you don't have to do it yourself.

Comment: No but then it shows ```&amp;amp;```